# Is there a way to allow compiler to optimize away multiple calls to an extern function?

Tags: c++, optimization, compile-time

I am constructing a C++ interface to a C library similar to this:

```
extern "C" {

typedef struct CFooStruct *CFoo;

int CFoo_getLength(CFoo);

// other functions

}
```

Currently I have

```
class MyFoo {
    CFoo foo;
    int len;
public:
    MyFoo(CFoo foo) : foo(foo), len(CFoo_getLength(foo)) { }

    int length() const { return len; } // inline function

    // other functions
};
```

The length is retrieved in the constructor and cached so that `MyFoo::length()` can be called repeatedly in a tight loop without a performance penalty.

When using the C interface directly, one would manually retrieve the length *once* if needed, then use it repeatedly.  If the length of a `CFoo` is not needed, then we would just never call `CFoo_getLength()`.

The C++ interface is meant to be simpler to use, and let the user just use `length()` without needing to think about performance.  The disadvantage of the above implementation is that it *always* calls `CFoo_getLength()` during the creation of every single `MyFoo` object, regardless of whether it will actually be used in the program.

Even though all member functions of `MyFoo` are inline, I believe the compiler won't optimize away the call to `CFoo_getLength()` because it has no way of knowing that this function has no side effects.

**Question:** Is there a way to implement this so that `CFoo_getLength()` will be called only if the length is actually used in the program?  (And that it is never called more than once for a `MyFoo` object?)  Is there a way to allow the compiler to optimize away the `CFoo_getLength()` call (if it is otherwise smart enough to deduce that it is not needed)?

---

One way would be to have a boolean flag in the class indicating whether the length has already been retrieved:

```
class MyFoo2 {
    CFoo foo;

    bool lenKnown = false;
    int len;
public:
    MyFoo2(CFoo foo) : foo(foo) { }

    int length() {
        if (!lenKnown) {
            len = CFoo_getLength(foo);
            lenKnown = true;
        }
        return len;
    }
};
```

But this is a runtime solution that makes `MyFoo` bigger and leads to extra computation within `MyFoo::length()`.  I was wondering if there is a compile-time solution.

Comment: You can get rid of the size penalty if the length of `CFoo` is indeed a length in the intuitive sense.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can you elaborate?  Conceptually, it does indicate a length, though I want to do similar things for a few other properties too.  However, `CFoo` is a pointer to an opaque struct whose structure I do not and cannot know.  The source code isn't available for this C library (only the headers).

Comment: For a true length, of the non-zero kind, you can use a negative value as an indicator instead of the boolean. I'm not aware of any compiler optimizations that can do that for you in the general sense. At the end of the day, I think you'll have to pay with either memory or run time.

Comment: Furthermore, If the function call is so costly that you are concerned over it (I hope you measured), then I fail to see why the "cost" of a simple conditional is any worry?

Comment: Does applying `__attribute__ ((const))` to `CFoo_getLength` help? I don’t think the compiler will be smart enough (either when setting `len` in the constructor or always calling `CFoo_getLength` in `length`), but it’s two things to try… apart from that, I guess you could split it into `MyFoo` and `MyFooWithLength`? That’s kind of awful though and doesn’t necessarily work for your situation either.

Comment: @Ryan With gcc 7.2, yes, it does!  https://godbolt.org/g/Fvwd9o  Try commenting it out, and the call to `CFoo_getLength` comes back

Comment: Wow, nice! Compilers are pretty amazing now.

Comment: @Ryan It also works with clang 5.0.  Will you post an answer?

Comment: I wouldn't be too eager. Have you tried with something that is a bit less toysih? https://godbolt.org/g/NuaHpB and not full of UB?

Comment: @StoryTeller: `std::rand()` isn’t pure, so you’re breaking the contract and requiring it to be evaluated for side-effects. (Not to say that I’m sure this will work all the time, but it needs a different example.)

Comment: @Ryan - The contract is already broken in the code the OP posted. They specified a function returning int, and omitted a return value. The compiler can do crazy things based of off that alone. It may not have anything to do with the attribute by itself.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It’s just a function prototype?

Comment: @Ryan - Apologies, I confused it when my own earlier faffing about. Regardless, the ODR violation is UB all on it's own. I'm not at all convinced this works as the OP wants in well-formed, non-trivial programs.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sorry, I’m not terribly familiar with C++ – where’s ODR violated in that example?

Comment: @Ryan - The OP provided an extern declaration of the function, **called it**  , but there is no definition of it anywhere the program. That's a one-definition-rule violation. The programs is officially ill-formed no diagnostic required. This means a compiler *may choose* accept it, but it has UB. That UB may be what is responsible for the attribute doing anything.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oh, okay. What’s the correct way to allow the implementation to be linked in from somewhere else, then? (And does this mean when I’m compiling individual `.cpp` files that include headers to `.o`s it’s dangerous?)

Comment: @Ryan - With online compilers, I cannot say. I don't actually have access to GCC at the moment to verify either. I'm not trying to rain on the parade, I just wanted to point out the OP needs to do some more serious testing, not just with godbold.

Comment: @Ryan - About your parethesized question. It's not dangerous. That ODR aspect pertains globally to the entire program, not to individual translation units. So as long as you linked everything in by the end, you are good to go.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't understand why this is an ODR violation. The definition of `CFoo_getLength` is in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Not in the online compiler it isn't. My whole point was that the fact it works in godbolt (where there *is* an ODR violation) is not indicative of whether or not it should work in general. But if it does, in your own project, good on ya :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the `pure` function attribute to mark `CFoo_getLength` as pure:

```
__attribute__ ((pure))
int CFoo_getLength(CFoo);
```

As you found, and to my C++-inexperienced surprise, it allows both gcc and clang to optimize your original code. Nice!

Comment: I am reading the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) and it seems that the appropriate attribute is actually `pure` (not `const`).  The docs say, "Note that a function that has pointer arguments and examines the data pointed to must not be declared const."  There is no such restriction on `pure`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yikes, I’ve misremembered. Thanks.